# How to test ng-select inside a Reactive Form?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect, angular-test

In my Angular app, I have a simple reactive form that uses [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) as one **required** inputs.

I also have a "Save" button that is enabled only when the form is valid.

Everything works fine.

I want to write a simple test case to make sure that the Save button is NOT enabled whenever the ng-select control has no value.

This is what I was able to do:

```
it('should not allow to save without a selected item', () => {
  component.form.get('myNgSelectControl').setValue('some-value');
  component.form.updateValueAndValidity();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(page.saveButton.disabled).toBe(false);

  component.form.get('myNgSelectControl').setValue(null);
  component.form.updateValueAndValidity();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(page.saveButton.disabled).toBe(true);
});
```

however I would like to build this test differently, I would like to simulate more the higher-level workflow: instead of manually setting the value to the form's control, I would like to do something like:

> "type value xxx in the ng-select"
>
> "select item xxx from the drop-down menu"

*( do the assertion that the Save button is now enabled )*

> "clear the selection by clicking on the 'X' of ng-select"

*( do the assertion that the Save button is now disabled )*

how can I accomplish this?

Comment: it looks like you are testing ngSelect in the new approach, IMHO, this should not be the concern of your unit tests.

Comment: what do you mean by "new approach"? I would like to test ng-select in a form just like I would test any other standard input or select field (without manually setting the control value via `component.form.get('myControl')`